# Return Indices Of Maximum Value in a Multidimensional Array in R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, max

Does R have a way to return the indices for the largest value in a multidimensional array?

I'm aware of the `which.max()` function for a vector, but I'm not sure if there is a similar way to return a set of indices for a multi-dimensional array.

For example, if I have a set of random values stored in a 35x55x1000 3D array:

`test <- array(rnorm(35*55*1000, mean=5, sd=1), dim=c(35,55,1000))`

and I want to find the indices related to the maximum value in in the 2D slice `test[,20,]`

using `which.max(test[,20,])` provides a single value, not a set of indices. Is there a way to do this without creating some sort of loop function (that might be slow)?

Comment: `test[,20,]` is a 2d array.  You may need to loop over the cols/rows `apply(test[,20,], 1, which.max)`

Comment: @akrun so a loop is the only way to do this?

Comment: @akrun What I'm after is the 2D indices that would map directly to the slice. E.g., if the output is `[12][30]` it would indicate the maximum value in `test[,20,]` is at `test[12,20,30]`. The function you provided above seems to provide multiple sets of 2D indices with distinctly different values

Comment: I am guessing that you want something like this `t(apply(test, 2, function(x) which(x == max(x), arr.ind = TRUE)))`

Comment: If you want a 3column index `m1 <- t(apply(test, 2, function(x) which(x == max(x), arr.ind = TRUE)));m2 <- cbind(m1[,1], seq_len(nrow(m1)), m1[,2])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This provides the answer I was looking for in the format of `[x1, x2, x3]` where `x2=20`:

`which( test==max(test[,20,],na.rm=T) , arr.ind = T )`

If the indices in the matrix are wanted without constraining it to a 2D by setting `x2=20`, you can use the below line:

`which( test==max(test,na.rm=T) , arr.ind = T )`

If there are multiple indices sets that have the same maximum value, you can select the first set from the list with

`which( test==max(test,na.rm=T) , arr.ind = T )[1,]`

Comment: In your question deleted yesterday, a correctly written version of you objective function will run correctly with `optim`. It iterates exactly 8 times going incrementally up and down for each parameter and when it finds no improvement in the local vlaue of the objective stops and announces "convergence".

Comment: @IRTFM how do you implement the constraints in your version of the objective function?

Comment: I corrected the dimensions of the matrix multiply and fixed the starting conditions, but left the logic the same. If you undelete the question I can post the code.

Comment: @IRTFM I appreciate the effort. I've undeleted the question ( I had originally deleted it because I decided to go with a diff. evolution method but look forward to your answer)